# How to change Mono mode for GvrEditorEmulator? (Not GvrViewerMain)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I wanna change Mono mode in Cardboard Application.
We could change it by setting "VRModeEnabled=false" in **GvrViewerMain** which is the main script in the old sdk version (1.4.0).
However, I cannot find the setting in **GvrEditorEmulator** which is the main script in the new sdk version (1.5.0).
Could you tell me the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The old SDKs were meant for unity version less than 5.6, where there is no native support for Cardboard / Daydream, and hence rendering had to be done with assistance from Google VR SDK. (GvrViewerMain). But now, with native render support added to Unity, the GvrViewerMain is obsoleted.. The GvrEditorEmulator just emulates inputs (head tracking, clicks ..).

You should be able to change the VRModeEnabled settings in the Unity "Player Preferences".